# copying 2 observable arrays and then comparing

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have declared 2 observable arrays as following in my code

```
self.versionDataByProduct = ko.observableArray([]);
self.copiedSavedVersionData = ko.observableArray([]);
```

When i save data i copy all value from self.versionDataByProduct into   self.copiedSavedVersionData  like below

```
 self.copiedSavedVersionData(self.versionDataByProduct());
```

Then i try to compare 2 observable array  on button event called compareArray like below

```
 this.compareArray = function () {
        debugger;
        var results = [];
        var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(self.versionDataByProduct(), self.copiedSavedVersionData());
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function (difference) {
            if (difference.status === "deleted") {
                results.push(difference.value);
            }
        });
        return results;
    };
```

But this doesnt work. Because after i copy one observable array to other and do some modification in observable array then it automatically updates other. I dont want that. I want my observable array self.copiedSavedVersionData to remain as is after it is copied. How can i achieve it? I am just doing it track if i have done any changes. If array is changed then i will enable button in my code. Currently i dont know how do i go about dirty tracking so found this alternative but not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice` function for this:

```
 self.copiedSavedVersionData(self.versionDataByProduct().slice(0));
```

In that case ko will clone array.

Comment: no it still copies content when i change something in self.versionDataByProduct()

Comment: hm.., should work. I tried this in a fiddle and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/jVdv7/

Comment: yes your code works but not sure what i am doing wrong. I have done exactly what you said. What will be other scenarios that it wont work

Comment: I know when its not working. In my code i make call to wcf service and if i try to copy observable arrays during it then it doesnt work.See code below
 var callback = function (data) {
        self.copiedSavedVersionData(self.versionDataByProduct().slice(0));
};

loadVersionDataBySelectedProduct(productId, callback);

if i move my code self.copiedSavedVersionData(self.versionDataByProduct().slice(0)); after its finished calling WCF service then it works

Comment: in my observable array self.copiedSavedVersionData there is one property called isSelected. I want to set it true. I tried like
self.copiedSavedVersionData().isSelected(true);      But doesnt work

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this in jsFiddle?

Comment: i had to make writeable computed observable then it works. Can you tell me how to create dirty flags? i think my method wont work. Its too tedious

Comment: Read this article - http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html. Or you can use dirty flag from koLite library - https://github.com/CodeSeven/kolite

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.copiedSavedVersionData, self.versionDataByProduct());
```